# I can't access ANY website: Connection refused (WSAECONNREFUSED)

Tags: windows, certificate

I have a Windows ultimate/32 PC.
Sometimes when I try to open Tor, the Launcher indicates "Connection Refused" as stated above.
Other times the Launcher message is "Tor failed to establish a Tor network connection - unexpected identity in router certificate". Still othertimes, Tor opens normally.

My question is: Does someone has an explanation for this behaviour?

Comment: Without logs, such problems are hard to debug. If you don't want to make them public, contacting the Tor help desk is a better solution: help@rt.torproject.org

Answer (score 2):

I had the same `'connection refused' [WSAECONNREFUSED]` error after upgrading my firewall (ZoneAlarm free, from 12.0.104 to 13.2.015) and I solved it this way:

1. Stop Tor (with button on Vidalia control panel)
2. Change 'firewall settings'
3. Start Tor again
4. Error? restart from step 1

I repeated these steps ~10 times to find out that I had to deactivate:

```
[ ] 'block secure server'
```

and

```
[ ] 'block public server'
```

Now Tor is running perfecty and I can surf again.